Azure Pipeline environment approval notification email content customize
I am using approval environment in my yaml pipeline. Mail is getting trigger for reviewer to approve. However I need to change content of notification email.
Here is the content in the email
"devops pipeline your approval is required for stage '__default' to use env-p-approval"
I want to modify to:
"devops pipeline your approval is required to move file for stage 'Production' to use env-p-approval"
Can I achieve this in azure devops?

Currently, Azure DevOps does not provide a direct way to modify the content of the approval notification emails. The default email content is generated by the system and cannot be customized directly within Azure DevOps.

devops pipeline your approval is required for stage '__default' to use env-p-approval.
devops pipeline your approval is required to move file for stage 'Production' to use env-p-approval.

It looks that the only difference is to add the words "to move file". If you want to add these key words to the approval, you can add instructions for the approvers when configure the approval.

Then it will show the instruction "move file" in the approval page.

